# How to get the post data in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the post information from the api and and after getting it I want call an api with the following information in django rest framework with the Token Authentication.I have seen there are some soln in stackoverflow but nothing is working here. Here is my code :

```
class DataInsertViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_data = request.data
        # HERE I WILL CALL API
        return Response(data=post_data , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But when I am running the api I am getting an error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/insertData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am not very sure what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestion will be a great help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this error is not from view,  provide full trackback error.

Comment: In the urlspatterns.py I forgot to add as_view(). But Now I am getting another error  `'DataInsertViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.` But I dont have a model class in the app. How should I overcome that

Comment: you should have to include model,  with **queryset="model_name"**,  unless model, **view** won't work.